When I am running zap in local it runs complete scan without any issues while when I run zap installed on an ec2 instance it fails with an error
Zap can be accessed publicly on ec2 instance using IP and PORT.
The error I received:
Proxy error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.102.0.156', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: http://zap/JSON/ascan/view/status/?scanId=0 (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000028E18540940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

from zapv2 import ZAPv2
import time
import requests

# ZAP API configuration
api_key =   # ZAP API Key
zap_ip = 
zap_port = '8080'
# Initialize the ZAP API client
zap = ZAPv2(apikey=api_key, proxies={
    'http': f'http://{zap_ip}:{zap_port}',
    'https': f'http://{zap_ip}:{zap_port}'
})
# JWT token
jwt_token = 'Bearer '  # Replace with your actual JWT token




# Swagger URL for the OpenAPI definition
swagger_url = 'https://inspired-mock-backend.sapidblue.in/v2/api-docs?group=Post Login Resource'
base_url = 'https://inspired-mock-backend.sapidblue.in/'

# Start a new session
zap.core.new_session(name='new_session', overwrite=True)

# Set custom headers for authentication (JWT)
zap.replacer.add_rule(description="Add JWT Authorization Header",
                      enabled=True,
                      matchtype="REQ_HEADER",
                      matchregex=False,
                      matchstring="Authorization",
                      replacement=jwt_token)

try:
    # Import the OpenAPI definition
    zap.openapi.import_url(swagger_url)

    print("Swagger definition imported successfully.")

    # Start an active scan on the base URL
    scan_id = zap.ascan.scan(base_url)
    print(f'Started Active Scan with ID: {scan_id}')

    # Monitor scan progress
    status = 0
    while int(zap.ascan.status(scan_id)) < 100:
        print(f'Scan progress: {zap.ascan.status(scan_id)}%')
        time.sleep(10)

    # Generate and save the HTML report
    html_report = zap.core.htmlreport()
    with open('zap_report.html', 'w') as report_file:
        report_file.write(html_report)

    print('HTML report saved as zap_report.html')

except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as e:
    print(f"Proxy error: {e}")
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print(f"Connection error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")




What options did you use to start ZAP?

The options you should use in order to connect to ZAP remotely are given on https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-can-i-connect-to-zap-remotely/
Also, you may well find that the Autiomation Framework is easier to use than the API: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/automation-framework/

Hi @SimonBennetts ,
Thanks for your response. I have setup zap in an ec2 instance and it accessible through
a public ip and port . The scan starts and when i run scan using this zap which is installed on public ip and port but it fails after partial completion throwing this error
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

When do you get that error? Is that from the first request you make to the API?
Have you checked the zap.log file?

after some amount of scan has been completed (it can 20% or 50% or even 90%) , i
Started Active Scan with ID: 0
Scan progress: 0%
Scan progress: 12%
Scan progress: 26%
Scan progress: 32%
Scan progress: 38%
Scan progress: 38%
